# Google Drive API's permission list inaccurate for Google Data Studio

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a Google Data Studio file which can be found with the Google Drive API, and I was able to get the permissions of the file. However, the permissions list seems inaccurate as some editors in the GDS file was left out. Here is the code used to retrieve the permissions of the file (which is pretty standard).

```
def get_permissions(id):
    page_token = ''
    all_results = []
    while page_token is not None:
        if page_token == '':
            results = SERVICES['v2'].permissions().list(fileId=id).execute()
        else:
            results = SERVICES['v2'].permissions().list(fileId=id, pageToken=page_token).execute().get('items',[])
        all_results += results.get('items',[])
        page_token = results.get('nextPageToken')
    return all_results
```

The File ID is correct and I even changed the owner to check if it picks up the new owner in the permissions list but somehow it is still missing.

Anyone else experienced this issue or have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue of `else branch` calling `get('items',[])`. Try this

```
def get_permissions(id):
    page_token = None
    all_results = []
    while True:
        results = SERVICES['v2'].permissions().list(fileId=id, pageToken=page_token).execute()
        all_results += results.get('items',[])
        page_token = results.get('nextPageToken')
        if page_token is None:
            break
    return all_results
```